# Any way to see the design in different size in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, multiple-sizes

Is there any way to see your design in different sizes in real-time in Illustrator/Photoshop? Like, designing an icon and you wanna see how it will look like in 16x16 or in 512x512?

I know you can `Save for web` in any size but that's cumbersome for every little tweak you make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can open many views of the same document (`Window > New Window`). Then just let the different views have different zoom levels.